# How can I use PHPUnit's DBUnit with a Microsoft SQL Server database?

Tags: php, sql-server, zend-framework, phpunit, dbunit

I'm using PHPUnit and DBUnit to create tests for a PHP application that runs on the commandline and inserts data into a Microsoft SQL Server database.

The DBUnit documentation (https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/database.html#database.supported-vendors-for-database-testing) states that Microsoft SQL Server is not supported but is accessible through the Zend Framework or Doctrine 2.

When I attempt:

```
 $pdo = new PDO( "odbc:Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server=redacted", $user, $passwd );

 $this->createDefaultDBConnection($pdo, $db);
```

I get, not surprisingly, the following error:

```
PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_Exception: Could not find a meta data driver for odbc pdo driver.
```

I found Zend Framework documentation that shows how to use PHPUnit to write tests related to relational databases (https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.test.phpunit.db.html), and I think I could get that to work if I understood Zend better, so it's possible what I need is some help understanding how to get access to the Zend classes w/out writing an entire Zend application.

But maybe there's some non-Zend way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is the PDO connection, I would recommend trying to use the pdo_sqlsrv driver that's bundled with the [SQL Server Driver for PHP](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098). The connection string you have to use would look something like this:

```
new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=localhost;Database=testdb", "UserName", "Password");
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like SQL Server Driver for PHP doesn't work with RHEL6, unfortunately. Even if it did, I don't think that means it would work with DBUnit, which explicitly only works with MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle and SQLite. I have already made a successful PDO connection using the MS ODBC Driver 13 for my main code, but the DBUnit package for PHPUnit seems to be checking the driver and only allowing the ones it supports.